# A quick riddle: what am I? Go ahead: Turn me upside-down

Tags: riddle

Go ahead: Turn me upside-down.

But others will soon realize your error.

Turn me back up, and the evidence is gone.

Don't blame me; It was *your* mistake.

I just give and, sometimes, take.

Comment: I have a hard time thinking of things that *don't* fit most of the lines.  Most things are not meant to be used upside down, and if you turn it back the right side up it becomes what it originally was.  If you turn something upside down that you're not supposed to, obviously it is your mistake and not the object's mistake.

Comment: Perhaps turning this particular object upside down is not an error, but a result of an error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is

> A pencil with an eraser in the back.

Go ahead: Turn me upside-down.

But others will soon realize your error.

> Turn a pencil upside down to use the eraser, when people see you erasing, they realize you made an error in your writing/drawing.

Turn me back up, and the evidence is gone.

> Turn the pencil back to its normal position and continue writing/drawing, as if you hadn't erased in the first place.

Don't blame me; It was your mistake.

> Your writing/drawing mistakes are your fault, not the fault of the pencil.

I just give and, sometimes, take.

> A pencil is used to "give" graphite to paper, but the eraser tip can be used to "take" graphite away from paper.

Comment: This also fits in with with OP's comment that turning it upside down is not an error by itself, but instead the result of an error.

Comment: Congratulations! That's what I was looking for :-D

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the last line, it sounds like:

> An Etch-A-Sketch

*Go ahead: Turn me upside-down.*

> Turning an etch-a-sketch upside down erases what's on the pad

*But others will soon realize your error.*

> Anyone else can see you've made a mistake if you're holding it upside down

*Turn me back up, and the evidence is gone.*

> No proof that anything is wrong now!

*Don't blame me; It was your mistake.*

> You drew something that didn't turn out as you'd have liked

*I just give and, sometimes, take.*

> Not sure here, which makes me doubt the whole answer

Second guess (to be elaborated on if correct):

> A magic 8 ball?

Comment: While your current answer isn't the one I'm looking for, I can tell you it's the closest one yet!

Comment: @K.Juice I've made a second attempt, but I'm less confident about it than I was the first

Comment: A good guess as well, but not the answer. Your first answer was closer! Keep trying!

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a:

> Credit card

Go ahead: Turn me upside-down.

But others will soon realize your error.

> Only works when you swipe it the right way up.

Turn me back up, and the evidence is gone.

> No harm done. Just turn it over and swipe again.

Don't blame me; It was your mistake.

> People blame the credit card when it doesn't go through.

I just give and, sometimes, take.

> Primarily used for purchases (giving), though sometimes you get reimbursed on it.

Another guess

> Pocket cards in poker

I'll explain way later

Comment: Interesting guess. Not the answer I'm looking for, however. Try again!

Comment: Okay, so it's something that's can be either up or down. One way it reveals information. The other way it doesn't. Revealing the information can be an error. And the object gives something either way, but sometimes takes something.

Comment: So if it's giving something physical, there must be a feed to it. More likely it's giving something metaphorical.

Comment: Maybe some sort of game token. Like a card.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be

> Time

Because

*Go ahead: Turn me upside-down.*

> Symbolism for metaphorically turning an hourglass upside-down, to regain time or relive moments

*But others will soon realize your error.*

> Most ambiguous line for me, perhaps indicates others notice the mistake you were trying to fix, or others see you are wasting your life trying to turn back time

*Turn me back up, and the evidence is gone.*

> You've wasted time trying to turn back time

Don't blame me; It was your mistake.

> Placing blame on time for going too quickly or not being able to revert decisions you made in the past

I just give and, sometimes, take.

> All living things die from old age

FYI:

> By 'turn back time', I do not mean literally. Think of that person you knew in high school that was very popular, but after school reality hit and they still haven't gotten over it, and whenever you see them they bring up moments that happened many years ago - (stuck in time?)

Comment: I might have guessed the object in your second spoiler, instead of the more abstract answer you gave...

Comment: I thought about it, but I couldn't fit it to the last line. I couldn't find an argument that supports that object literally or metaphorically giving or taking.

Comment: A very interesting guess! It's one I hadn't even considered when I wrote the riddle. While your guess *mostly* fits, it is not the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here I will try to be funny:

> It's Grandma in dress!

Go ahead: Turn me upside-down.
But others will soon realize your error.

> Yup, it's just wrong...

Turn me back up, and the evidence is gone.

> See! nothing happened

Don't blame me; It was your mistake.

> Shouldn't prank on grandma you little brat

I just give and, sometimes, take.

> love, cookies, well many other things

Comment: I'm starting to wonder why I didn't make this riddle about flipping my grandma upside-down in the first place. Sorry, but your answer isn't right (on more than one level ;-P)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is

> An ant farm.

Go ahead: Turn me upside-down.

> You can turn an ant farm upside down if you really wanted.

But others will soon realize your error.

> Most people would recognize if an ant farm was oriented the wrong way.

Turn me back up, and the evidence is gone.

> Once you turn it over, chances are that the tunnels have all collapsed/filled, and you can no longer see anything.

Don't blame me; It was your mistake.

> The ants didn't do anything, but you now have a bunch of dead ants.

I just give and, sometimes, take.

> Ant farms give a lot of joy to curious young minds, but ants also take things... from everywhere.

Comment: Very creative! But it's not really what I'm looking for. However, I now have a desire to go buy an ant farm :-)

Comment: @K.Juice Then I have succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's:

> A diode.

*Go ahead: Turn me upside-down.

But others will soon realize your error.*

> No more flow!

*Turn me back up, and the evidence is gone.*

> What do you mean? The system is running fine!

*Don't blame me; It was your mistake.*

> These are put in backwards all the time (I've done it)

*I just give and, sometimes, take.*

> LEDs give light!

Comment: A clever answer, but not what I'm looking for. Give it another shot!

Answer (score 1):

Could this be

> an Hourglass?

Go ahead: Turn me upside-down.

> You turn an hourglass upside down to stop the flow of the sand and reverse it.

But others will soon realize your error.

> Assuming it is an unembellished hourglass, when you turn it upside down the differential in sand will show that it has been changed.  They will also notice if they are especially perceptive of the passage of time and notice that the sand completely drains either too quickly or too slowly.

Turn me back up, and the evidence is gone.

> If you flip the hourglass to its original position, there will be nothing to prove that it was tampered with, unless the *others* are of a scientific mind, and have graduated lines on their hourglass, or at least a separate, control hourglass.

Don't blame me; It was your mistake.

> In turning the hourglass over you lose the time it was keeping track of.  It would have kept fine time if it had been undisturbed, but turning it over kept it from serving its purpose.

I just give and, sometimes, take.

> One half of the hourglass gives sand, while the other half takes it (with a little help from gravity and an excess of space).

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm looking for. You appear to be extremely analytical! However, don't over-analyze this riddle. The correct answer needs much less explanation. Also, wouldn't an hour-glass always give and take in equal amounts? The correct answer only takes *sometimes*. Have another go at it!

Answer (score 1):

Could it possibly be:

> A painting?

Go ahead: Turn me upside-down.

> It's quite easy to hang a painting the the wrong way, especially if the painting is abstract.

But others will soon realize your error.

> Anyone familiar with the painting will know it's upside-down.

Turn me back up, and the evidence is gone.

> If you turn it back up, no one will know it was ever upside-down.

Don't blame me; It was *your* mistake.

> Obviously, I put the painting upside-down, so it's my fault.

I just give and, sometimes, take.

> Paintings and other works of art can give people enjoyment and insight. Sometimes, people even take away a deeper meaning!

Comment: Interesting guess. Couldn't the same be said for many different things? You could put flowers upside-down in a vase, flip your grandmother upside-down (as someone else guessed), and they all give/take in some way. What I'm looking for literally gives and takes. Try again!

Comment: @K.Juice Darn! I was hoping since panting could be easily put upside-down, it might be an answer! I'll be back if I think of anything better!